# Cut a navigation bar with different colors (with CSS 2.1)

Tags: zooming, slice, navigationbar, css

Please help me cut the following navigation bar using CSS2.1, with shadow, rounded borders and without spoiling the layout if you zoom-in/zoom-out:

[image]

Already two days I have been working on it, and could not find any way which will look the same look while zooming...

EDIT:

- need to be done with **CSS2.1**
- right and left borders are rounded + have shadow (right left correspondingly)
- there is a shadow on bottom as well

Comment: Can you point a tutorial which slices something like this?

Comment: Here I have tried but it does not work while I zoom: http://profsyntax.com/test/7Days/

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple enough.

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="news" style="background-color: black;">News</a><a href="business" style="background-color: orange;">Business</a>......<a href="deals" style="background-color: blue;">Deals</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar > a {
   padding: 10px;
   box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px black;
   color: white;
}
#navbar > a:first-child { border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px; }
#navbar > a:last-child { border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px; }
```

Comment: Box shadow is CSS3, but I have to use css2.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple solution. You can use just css. I used jQuery to assing the colors but it's a straightforward process...
http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/QtLv5/2/

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
li { float: left; }
a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font: bold 15px Arial;
}

/* If you assign unique ids to your menu items you can do */
#item { background: red; }
```

​

Comment: Ohhh, no! The right and left borders are rounded, there is a shadow below the buttons and on the right and left sides.

Comment: If you want those effects without css3 then you'll have to use images.

Comment: Yes, I do exactly that. But I don't know how to achive consistent layout when it is zoom in/out